# The category theoretic origin of arithmetic product

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory

$\newcommand\Bij{\mathrm{Bij}}\newcommand\Set{\mathrm{Set}}\newcommand\Species{\mathrm{Species}}$The paper "[On the arithmetic product of combinatorial species](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2007.09.062)" by Maia and Méndez introduces a combinatorial interpretation for the arithmetic product of two combinatorial species $M$, $N$.

In short, let $F:\Bij\to \Set$ be a (finite) combinatorial species and define its (modified) Dirichlet series to be
$$ D_F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|F[n]|}{n!n^s}$$ where $|F[n]|$ is the cardinality of the set $F[n]$. Then, the arithmetic product $\boxdot$ is a monoidal operation on the category of species such that $D_{M\boxdot N}(s)=D_M(s)D_N(s)$.

Explicitly, one takes an (exponential) power series $\sum \frac{a_n}{n!}X^n$ for the species $M$, and one $\sum \frac{b_n}{n!}X^n$ for $N$, and their arithmetic product is
$$\newcommand\mbinom{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}} \sum \frac{c_n}{n!}X^n \qquad c_n := \sum_{d\mid n} \mbinom n d a_db_{n/d}$$ (there is an unfortunate clash of notation between this notation and Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind here, but $\mbinom n d$ is just the "modified binomial" $\frac{n!}{d!(n/d)!}$).

With sparse remarks here and there, the paper proves what boils down to the fact that the category of species has a symmetric monoidal structure given by $\boxdot$. The only thing is, usually Dirichlet series and their convolution are not defined in this way, but instead without the $\frac 1{n!}$. At any rate, it seems to me that with the appropriate substitution/transport of structure the monoidal category $(\Species,+,\boxdot)$ can be regarded as a categorified version of the semiring of Dirichlet series with nonnegative integer coefficients.

My question is: is there a description of this monoidal structure that looks concise to a category theorist, or at least as concise as all other monoidal structures (Cartesian, Day convolution, substitution…) do? What is the universal property, if any, of the $\boxdot$ structure? (Compare this question with: the substitution product of species is the unique monoidal structure making $\Species$ monoidally equivalent to the category of analytic functors + composition, and it's called "substitution product" because it coincides with the composition of formal power series $(\sum a_n t^n)\circ g = \sum a_n g(t)^n$).

My understanding is that this structure is *related* to the substitution product (obtained as iterated convolution) which is what the authors (and other people studying species with more combinatorial jargon) call "assemblies": indeed, they say:

> The most interesting combinatorial construction associated to the arithmetic product is the assembly of cloned
> structures. Informally, an assembly of cloned $G$-structures is an assembly of $G$-structures in the above sense, where
> all structures in the assembly are isomorphic replicas of the same structure. Moreover, information about ‘homologous
> vertices’ or ‘genetic similarity’ between each pair in the assembly is also provided. The structures of $F \boxdot G$ have
> some resemblance with the structures of the substitution $F(G)$. An element of $F \boxdot G$ can be represented as a cloned
> assembly of $G$-structures together with an external $F$-structure (an $F$-assembly of cloned $G$-structures). Because
> of the symmetry $F \boxdot G = G \boxdot F$ this structures can also be represented as $G$-assemblies of cloned $F$-structures.
> For example, if $L_+$ denotes the species of non-empty lists, the structures of $F \boxdot L_+$ could be thought of either as
> $F$-assemblies of cloned lists, or as lists of cloned $F$-structures.

But I'm having a really hard time even understanding what is the notion of a "rectangle" that the authors employ to give to $\boxdot$ a combinatorial interpretation (for example: the authors employ notation from combinatorics that is not introduced, because I believe it's standard, but very far from my knowledge). I reason way better with coends and Kan extensions….

Comment: TeX note: "generalised fractions" simulated like $\begin{Bmatrix}n\\d\end{Bmatrix}$ `\begin{Bmatrix}n\\d\end{Bmatrix}` and $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\d\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ `\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\ d\end{smallmatrix}\right\}` "want to" be instances of `\genfrac`, which takes 6 (!) arguments.  For our purposes, the relevant ones are the first two (delimiters), third (thickness of the fraction bar), and last two (numerator and denominator). E.g., to have a command `\mbinom` for generalised binomials, use `\newcommand\mbinom{\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}}`. I edited accordingly.

Comment: I am as careful to these things when I write pdfs, as I am completely careless here on MO :-) "inside you there are two wolves"...

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461268/the-category-theoretic-origin-of-arithmetic-product#comment1196360_461268), fair enough!  Then I hope that the comment can still be of interest to some passersby who might use MO for TeX inspiration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The arithmetic product is indeed obtained by Day convolution – it is induced by the product of natural numbers – and is studied as the *matrix monoidal structure* of Dwyer–Hess's [The Boardman-Vogt tensor product of operadic bimodules](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3711). (The connection between the arithmetic product and matrix product is observed in Bremner–Dotsenko's [Boardman–Vogt tensor products of absolutely free operads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04573).)

That the arithmetic product interacts nicely with the substitution monoidal structure to form a normal duoidal structure was proven by Garner and López Franco in §6 of [Commutativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.08710).

Providing a more abstract understanding of the arithmetic product is the motivation for the recent preprint [Monoidal Kleisli Bicategories and the Arithmetic Product of Coloured Symmetric Sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.06858) by Gambino, Garner, and Vasilakopoulou, in which the authors derive an arithmetic product structure on categorical symmetric sequences / generalised species, which restricts to the arithmetic product of Maia and Méndez (see §10 in particular). The introduction of this paper also provides a good survey on the topic.